# Why does audio work in the simulator but not on my iPad?

Tags: xcode, ipad, ios4, avaudioplayer, ios-simulator

I am working on creating a very simple app.  2 buttons, both play sound.  Each clip lasts 1 second and responds to "TouchUpInside".  They are .caf files that I converted in iTunes.

Here is my code, once again, it works in the simulator but not on the device:

```
enter code here- (void)viewDidLoad {

    NSLog(@"InView did load");

AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID ((CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"bigaif" ofType:@"caf"]], &systemSoundID);


    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] 
                                                                   pathForResource: @"smallwav" ofType:@"wav"]],                                                            
                                                                    &systemSoundIDTwo);
```

}

```
-(IBAction) playSound:(id) sender {
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(systemSoundID);
}

-(IBAction) playSoundTwo:(id) sender {
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(systemSoundIDTwo);
```

}

Comment: Do not have any problems with filenames? Faced with the fact that the mac was set to casemapping and due to a typo in the file name was the same situation

Comment: Well, I figured it out by myself.  I wanted to post the solution so others don't make this mistake.  When using "SystemSound", make sure you have your system sounds turned up in your settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found my answer.  I was using SystemSound and what do you know, I had my system sounds muted in my device settings.

Comment: This setting can be changed also with the mute button on the side of the device next to volume buttons.

Comment: Somewhat similar problem. Fixed by going into settings and turning up the volume on Sounds->Ringer and Alerts

Answer (score 15):

After looking for errors in my code for the past 30 min I found that the mute button on the side of iPad was on. Check that before trying some fancy solution.

30 min well spent...

Answer (score 3):

I had same issue. I didn't add a link reference to the AudioToolbox.framework but it still worked on simulator.
I added it and it played in the foreground of my app on the device.

Then I wanted it to play the sound in the background. In `info.plist` "Required background modes" add the key "**plays audio**". That got it working the background.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me as well.  Sounds were playing just fine in the simulator, but not on the device.  I tried to play the sounds multiple different ways.  I used both SystemSound and AVAudioPlayer with the same results.  I even [downloaded the code from a Mobile Orchard](http://mobileorchard.com/easy-audio-playback-with-avaudioplayer/) tutorial, and had the same result.  Code example worked fine in simulator, but wouldn't play on the device.

After 2 hours of this, I double-tapped the home button on the iPad, scrolled to the left to the sound controls, and then tapped the speaker icon on the left.  That placed a slash through the speaker icon to indicate that system volume was muted.  I then tapped again, the slash went away, and I was then able to play sounds through the device.

So basically, I had to toggle through the muted state of the device using this method and that reset something on the iPad to where I could hear the sounds.

Note that this was on iOS6.